# Turkey visa refused. How to re-apply?

Tags: indian-citizens, visa-refusals, turkey

Applied for Turkey Tourist visa and it's refused without informing any reason. I am working as a Software Engineer. I am from Kerela, India and by checking Turkish embassy site, I can reapply only after one year. I came to know that Schengen visa holders can travel to Turkey without having visa. I would like to know that, if I get a Schengen visa, then I can go to Turkey without visiting Schengen country ? Or any other options are available ?

I have normal Indian Passport.

I applied in the website http://www.konsolosluk.gov.tr/
Detailed information collected from http://www.vfsglobal.com/

Comment: Did you apply for an eVisa or a regular sticker visa ? Indian citizens are eligible for eVisas

Comment: By their site https://www.evisa.gov.tr/en/info/  Indian citizens are not eligible to apply eVisa.

Comment: India is in the [list](https://www.evisa.gov.tr/en/info/who-is-eligible-for-e-visa/) of eligible countries, and you can select India from the menu to apply for an [eVisa](https://www.evisa.gov.tr/en/apply/)

Comment: Yes, sorry for the mistake. Indian's can apply, but as per their site,  **I have a valid Supporting Document (Valid visa OR valid residence permit from one of the Schengen Countries, USA, UK or Ireland). E-visas are not accepted as supporting documents.**

Comment: Quite right, so you applied for a sticker visa then. They must have specified why you were refused though, did you get a letter back ? Did you call and ask ?

Comment: Yes, I called to Turkish embassy and they told that, "The Consulate reserves the right for not sharing the reason and cause for rejecting a Visa application."

Comment: Wow, that's odd. Nothing prevents you from applying for a Schengen visa and not using it, of course once you have a Schengen visa you're then eligible for a Turkish evisa

Comment: If we have Schengen visa, then we must apply eVisa ? Can we go directly to Turkey and get an on arrival Visa from there ?

Comment: Did they tell you that the 1-year reapplication ban applies also to e-Visas?  Did you ask?

Comment: No you don't have to, I'm just saying you would be eligible. Also, India doesn't seem to figure in the [list](http://www.mfa.gov.tr/data/KONSOLOSLUK/e-visa-fees-en-31-december.pdf) of countries eligible for visa on arrival

Comment: @phoog Yes, I asked to Embassy and they told that, you can reapply after 6 month minimum. But in the site, we can apply after 1 year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you're going to have to wait out your ban.

India is on the list of visa [countries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Turkey#Conditional_e-Visa), and isn't on the [list](http://www.mfa.gov.tr/visa-information-for-foreigners.en.mfa) of [visa on arrival](http://www.mfa.gov.tr/data/KONSOLOSLUK/vize-harc-miktarlari-en.pdf) ones. This means you have to have one, whether an eVisa or a sticker. Having a Schengen visa makes you [eligible](https://www.evisa.gov.tr/en/info/what-are-the-criteria-for-the-validity-of-my-supporting-document-visa-or-residence-permit-from-schengen-or-from-us-uk-and-ireland/) for an eVisa but doesn't exempt you from needing one.

It is possible to [appeal](https://www.konsolosluk.gov.tr/Faq/Index) the decision, note however this could take longer than your ban period, depending on procedure.

> **HOW CAN I APPEAL IF MY APPLICATION IS REJECTED?**
>   Appeal against the rejection of the visa application is made firstly by applying in writing to the agency who refused a visa. If not receiving a positive response, it is possible to apply to a court for appeal. However, the country is open to judicial review of the visa denial are not outnumbered. Also, often time-consuming court process likely to result in the end of the court against the state is weak. Another important aspect, it keeps open to the objection of a state of law in the judicial visa applicants, this case will be looked at the court of that state. Therefore, it is necessary to keep a lawyer in the country.